# How can i do so that my chartjs updates everytime data is inserted or by time interval?

Tags: javascript, php, pdo, chart.js

I have a chartjs that use variables as data. and i want it to be updating so that new data can be seen. Would be best if i could do it with when data is inserted but i have no clue of how to do that, other option would be to update with time interval. **I have looked at the https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html but it didnt make sense to me**

Here is my code **THE CHART WORKS JUST NEED TO MAKE IT UPDATE ON ITS OWN**

```
<div class="row bg-dark">
    <div class="col-12 border">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <?php
      $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT Actual FROM csvhoejde1");
      $sth->execute();
      /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
      $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
      // $result = explode("@", implode(",@", $result));
      // print_r for at se resultaterne.
      echo'<pre>';
      print_r($result);
      echo'</pre>';
      $std = $db->prepare("SELECT Dato_ur_stillet FROM palle_tbs");
      $std->execute();
      /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
      $palle = $std->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    ?>
  <div>
</div>
  <!----------------------myChart---------------------->
  <script src="./assets/charts/dist/Chart.js"></script>
<script>



var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var horizonalLinePlugin = {
  afterDraw: function(chartInstance) {
    var yScale = chartInstance.scales["y-axis-0"];
    var canvas = chartInstance.chart;
    var ctx = canvas.ctx;
    var index;
    var line;
    var style;

    if (chartInstance.options.horizontalLine) {
      for (index = 0; index < chartInstance.options.horizontalLine.length; index++) {
        line = chartInstance.options.horizontalLine[index];

        if (!line.style) {
          style = "rgba(169,169,169, .6)";
        } else {
          style = line.style;
        }

        if (line.y) {
          yValue = yScale.getPixelForValue(line.y);
        } else {
          yValue = 0;
        }

        ctx.lineWidth = 3;

        if (yValue) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(0, yValue);
          ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, yValue);
          ctx.strokeStyle = style;
          ctx.stroke();
        }

        if (line.text) {
          ctx.fillStyle = style;
          ctx.fillText(line.text, 0, yValue + ctx.lineWidth);
        }
      }
      return;
    };
  }
};
Chart.pluginService.register(horizonalLinePlugin);

var data = {
  labels: [<?php echo join($palle, ',') ?>],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 4,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: [<?php echo join($result, ',') ?>],
  }]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    "horizontalLine": [{
      "y": 140,
      "style": "rgba(255, 0, 0, .4)",
    }, {
      "y": 120,
      "style": "#00ffff",
    }]
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check `chart.update()` method? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Yes but i didnt understand how i should use it. can you explain it to me or give an example?

Comment: Are you using any library like JQuery or just vanilla javascript?

Comment: Move PHP code in separate file that produces needed JSON(s). Then make JavaScript AJAX calls to fetch the data, i.e. to consume this/these JSON(s) - once or on a certain interval. After each fetch, just call `update()` method;

Comment: Yeah mixing AJAX call with the code in addData will do perfectly. Just make sure ctx is accessible by this new method since its the chart object which is to be updated. And just pass the same labels and updated data in the method. It should be solved.

Comment: what do i do with `data: [<?php echo join($result, ',') ?>]`

Comment: i do use jquery `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could implement this.

The easiest but probably "worst" solution would be to simply refresh the page every x seconds. 
This solution will however make almost any interactivity on the page useless as inputs etc. will all reset each time the page refreshes.
Put the following in your `<head>` section.
`content` will define how many seconds between each refresh.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5">
```

Comment: as i dont insert any data in the part of the site it would be a cheap solution. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Any other solution would probably require a backend that provides an endpoint to fetch the data in an interval.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use `setInterval` which calls function to update chart(see example: https://jsbin.com/yitep/5/edit?html,js,output).

Or next solution would be to add a function which you will call on data insert. You can update chart by calling in your case `myChart.update()`.
It somethimes can happen that you don't have or can't get chart instance, in this case you can use(that's only way to get instance, you will need that if code is executed in another script):

```
    Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (chart) {
        // your code
    }
```

Now when you have chart instance you can manipulate with data, use `addData` and `removeData`(check in docs how it works).

Problem is that it goes through all charts, so you need to check somehow what is target chart, you can do this with `chart.chart.canvas.id`. This command will give you canvas chart id, in your case `myChart` so you can do only changes on charts what you choose.

For getting chart options you can use chart api event `chart.getDatasetMeta(0)`(check docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html).

Hope it helps, feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll look more into it!